# UIView missing background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

My application's structure looks like:

- UIViewController1

  ```
   - UIViewController2

             - Add UIView programmatically
  ```

UIViewController1 contains UIViewController2, and I add some UIView, loading from Xib, to the UIViewController2 with the following code:

```
SessionView* b = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SessionView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
[self.view addSubview:b];

//- set Frame before or after addSubView, there is no difference
CGRect frame = b.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
b.frame = frame;
```

The original UIView looks like this:

[image: Original UIView]

After adding to the UIViewController, it looks like this:

[image: After Adding]

With the following code, when I assign the width and height of the UIView equal to a part of the width and height of the main view, it looks good

```
SessionView* b = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SessionView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    [self.view addSubview:b];
    CGRect frame = b.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    //------- Assign the Width and Height Value
    //-------------------------------------------
    frame.size.width = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) / 3;
    frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) / 3;

    b.frame = frame;
```

[image: acceptable]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are adding `viewController` directly as subview, instead you should be adding `view` of `viewController` as subview.

```
SessionView* b = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SessionView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
[self.view addSubview:b.view];
```

Comment: Thanks, but SessionView is a UIView, not a UIViewController.

Comment: If its view then how could you load it as `xib`?

Comment: agreed, but you need to `subclass` it of `UIView`, have you created `.h & .m` files for it? if `NO` create it and it will work because you have some operation to perform on it.

Comment: Yes. I create a subclass of UIView with .h & .m and xib file as you see in the picture I showed above.

Comment: if you read [referenced blog](http://eppz.eu/blog/uiview-from-xib/) it clearly mentioned that, T`his approach works only in really the case when you don’t need anything else just a view assembled in Interface Builder without any communication bindings.` you can't use `UIView` as `ViewController` by creating `xib`. i hope you understand it.

Comment: I will take a look into it more carefully. Maybe, it could be a problem.